# "Actual size" is greyed out in QuickTime Player in 10.10.4

Tags: macos, video, quicktime

Whenever I am playing any movies in QuickTime, the "Actual Size" option is greyed out. Even the shortcut does not work. In Mavericks, it was working.

In this image, I am playing a full HD video, but it's playing at 1440x810. The Actual size is greyed out. How can I play it at full resolution.

[image]

Comment: What's your screen rez? If it's 1920x1080 then it will only play at full size in Fullscreen mode. Fullscreen will ungrey when you put the Inspector away.

Comment: It's 1440x900. I have put Inspector there to show the video size. It's always  greyed out.

Comment: If your screen rez is 1440x900 then that's as big as you're gonna get

Comment: But QT was able to play at full resolution previously. May be it was 10.8 or 10.9. In 10.10, they might have removed.

Comment: How can you play at a higher rez than your screen?

Comment: The video was going beyond the screen. For example, see a 5K photo at full resolution on a normal screen in Preview. Just like that.